# WPF MVVM list of empty textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi I'm a beginner in WPF and MVVM and I base on [Creating an Internationalized Wizard in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF).

I want to create wizard to choose exercise and amount. My goal is something like this: 
[First step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHpHf.jpg)

Can I add empty texboxes to view using List<> like in the case of checkboxes? I will need textbox value in next steps.
My ExerciseView below:

**XAML**

```
<GroupBox
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Header="Amount"
        Padding="2"
        Grid.Column="1"
        >
        <ItemsControl FontWeight="Normal" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableExerciseAmount}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox
                            Width="20"                         
                            Margin="2,3.5"
                            />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </GroupBox>
```

And optional textbox should be available only if the right checkbox is selected.

I have no idea how to resolve my problem. I am open for suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: depending on your preference, you can bind visibility or `enabled` or `readonly` status of your textbox to `checked` property of your checkbox. By this way, they will be automatically configured as the user clicks on your checkbox.